# c++ check cdrom status

Tags: c++, windows, cd-rom

Does anyone have a good way to check the status of a CDROM drive, and wait for it to be fully initialized and ready before trying to access it?

Currently I am using Win32_CDROMDrive from the WMI. I check the 'MediaLoaded' and wait until it changes from 'false' to 'true'. This works 90% of the time, but every now and then, I get an error from the OS saying that it expected the previous volume (CD) to still be in the drive.

Workflow:
       1. insert cd
       1.5 wait for 'MediaLoaded' flag
       2. process data
       3. eject cd
       4. start over.

WinXP 32bit, c++

Answer (score 2):

Do you know the drive letter for the CDROM? If so, could you just call GetVolumeInformation() or perhaps FindFirstFile() periodically, and wait until it succeeds?

Comment: I'd also recommend `GetVolumeInformation()` as the most reliable method. I've used it in a Python script when I had to process a couple hundred discs (much like OP's scenario). It never failed.